# HostingEnvironment.MapPath does not work with Owin self-hosting option

Tags: asp.net, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to load a file on a self-hosted Owin based server.

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:3001/");
```

Here is how I map the path:

```
var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~");
```

it always returns null!

On the other hand, if the website is hosted in IIS (or express) the value of path is right.
How can I can populate this value for the Self-Hosted owin?

Answer (score 1):

As owin self-hosting doesn't use iis, instead of virtual path, the absolute path should be used.

```
var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~");
if (path == null)
{
    var uriPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
    path = new Uri(uriPath).LocalPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When running under OWIN under dnx, I found that many of the suggested workarounds around reading the current app domain would return the .dnx runttime folder - not the web app location.

Here's what worked for me inside OWIN startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {

            app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                var hostingEnvironment = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();
                var realPath = hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + ctx.Request.Path.Value;

                // do something with the real file -path

                await next();
            });
```